# How can i calculate the percentages progress of Process and report to backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i want to report is the percentages until the convertion of the file is over. How to calculate the percentages and how to report it to the progressBar ?

I added a progressBar1 to the form1 designer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConvertVideo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string InputFile = @"e:\lightningsmov\MVI_7909.MOV";
        string OutputFile = @"e:\lightningsmov\MVI_7909";
        string cmd;
        string exepath = @"E:\myffmpegstatic\ffmpeg-20151217-git-9d1fb9e-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label2.Text = InputFile;
            cmd = " -i \"" + InputFile + "\" \"" + OutputFile + ".mp4" + "\"";
        }

        private void ConvertNow(string cmd)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            proc.Start();
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress()
            while (proc.HasExited == false)
            {

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ConvertNow(cmd);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What i tried so far is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ConvertVideo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string InputFile = @"e:\lightningsmov\MVI_7909.MOV";
        string OutputFile = @"e:\lightningsmov\MVI_7909.mp4";
        string cmd;
        string exepath = @"E:\myffmpegstatic\ffmpeg-20151217-git-9d1fb9e-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
        FileInfo fi;
        int totalBytes = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            fi = new FileInfo(InputFile);
            label2.Text = InputFile;
            cmd = " -i \"" + InputFile + "\" \"" + OutputFile + "\"";
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void ConvertNow(string cmd)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            proc.Start();

            // Gets the size of the file in bytes.
        Int64 iSize = fi.Length;

        int intProgress = 0;
        // Keeps track of the total bytes downloaded so we can update the progress bar.
        Int64 iRunningByteTotal = 0;
            // Open the input file for reading.
        using (FileStream InputFile = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            // Using the FileStream object, we can write the output file.
            using (FileStream OutputFiles = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                // Loop the stream and get the file into the byte buffer.
                int iByteSize = 0;
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[iSize];

                while ((iByteSize = InputFile.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)                    
                {
                    // Calculate the progress out of a base "100."
                    double dIndex;
                    double dTotal;
                    double dProgressPercentage;
                    // Write the bytes to the file system at the file path specified.                        
                    dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                    dTotal = (double)byteBuffer.Length;
                    dProgressPercentage = (dIndex / dTotal);
                    OutputFiles.Write(byteBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
                    iRunningByteTotal += iByteSize;
                    intProgress = Convert.ToUInt16(dProgressPercentage);
                    // Update the progress bar.
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(100 * iRunningByteTotal / iSize));

                }                    
                // Close the output file.
                OutputFiles.Close();
            }
            // Close the input file.
            InputFile.Close();
        }


            while (proc.HasExited == false)
            {

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ConvertNow(cmd);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But getting exception on the line:

```
using (FileStream OutputFiles = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
```

The exception say the file is in use by another process.
I guess it's in use with the Process(proc the ffmpeg).

So i guess i messed it up and using the FileStream is a good idea.

Comment: You have to read the output result through process info and figure it out the percentage. I did the same for converting videos using *ffmpeg*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines

```
// Open the input file for reading.    
using (FileStream InputFile = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    // Using the FileStream object, we can write the output file.
    using (FileStream OutputFiles = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        //Your other codes
    }
}
```

Seem to have the same `OutputFile` as an input, plus different `FileMode` and `FileAccess`. That causes the violation.

You should change your first `OutputFile` with `InputFile` then everything would be fine.

Comment: Ian i changed it the first one using (FileStream InputFile i changed it to: new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)) before it was OutputFile. But now i'm getting errors: Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle' and Error 4 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileMode' to 'System.IO.FileAccess' and Error 5 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileAccess' to 'int' and Error 6 Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileShare' to 'bool'

Comment: In which line do you get it?

Comment: In the line: using (FileStream InputFile = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)) i changed the OutputFile to InputFile then getting the errors on this line. This is the first using

Comment: This is quite different problem from the original post, I think. I am unable to duplicate your problem here. Perhaps there are something else which I miss here which you have done in yours. But from your error, perhaps you want to see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle(v=vs.110).aspx